# Is eval and execute still dangerous in ASP/VBScript if no user-defined data get passed through them?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

This is more of an "ethical" question than a technical question.

It's very obvious why `Eval()` and `Execute()` are dangerous if you allow user-defined data/variables to get passed through them. However, I've always gotten the vibe that the use of these functions is frowned upon no matter what and are only to be used as a last resort.

Anyway, I've used them here and there when it can make coding more efficient and dynamic... but I always make sure I know that what gets passed through the functions are controlled and not user-defined. Would you consider this bad coding? Is there a way a hacker could take advantage of those functions even if it's not reading anything defined by `Request` or `Session` variables or any other user-defined data?

Comment: This is opinion based question so likely will be closed, but I would say used them in the past with no issue. In fact for certain situations they are very useful. Example building ajax server-side scripts that match ajax calls to server-side functions including parameters is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you pass into the Eval() or Execute() is *purely your own string, without any input the user can influence whatsoever*, then it should be safe.
However, this also renders a lot of the possibilities of Eval() and Execute() useless.

For example, it is very tempting to use Eval() and Execute() for creating API-like functions, where a user calls a function in a querystring, and you simpley Eval() it instead of using a big select...case for every possible call.
I have also seen it used in CSV parsing, where column names are mapped to recordset-columns using eval(), again, very useful, but extremely dangerous, but you have already demonstrated in your question you are aware of that.

If you are absolutely sure the parsed code is under your complete control, it's very poweerful.

Answer (score 1):

If it's any help, I use this function to replace Eval to a certain degree. It allows you to specify which functions are valid in Eval. To use it simply call `Calculate(`*expression*`)`.

```vbs
'Calculation limitations for use with Calculate function...
Const C_VALID_CALC_CHARS        = "0123456789.+-*/()^\=,"
'NOTE: Deliberately broken this const so that it is readable in StackOverflow...
Const C_VALID_CALC_FUNCTIONS    = " Abs Asc Atn CBool CByte CCur CDate 
    CDbl Chr CInt CLng Cos CSng CStr Date DateAdd DateDiff DatePart 
    DateSerial DateValue Day Escape Exp FormatCurrency FormatDateTime 
    FormatNumber FormatPercent GetLocale Hex Hour InStr InStrRev Int Fix 
    IsDate IsEmpty IsNull IsNumeric LCase Left Len Log LTrim RTrim Trim 
    Maths Mid Minute Month MonthName Now Oct Replace Right Rnd Round Second 
    Sgn Sin Space Split Sqr StrComp String StrReverse Tan Time Timer 
    TimeSerial TimeValue UCase Unescape Weekday WeekdayName Year "


'Calculate
'   Calculates the expression string and returns a value.
'Usage:
'   value = Calculate("Sin(43) * Cos(75)")
'Parameters:
'   expression (string) - A string value containing the expression to be evaluated.
'Notes:
'   This function provides a controlled method for evaluating specific 
'   functions but has been severly limited to minimise negative effects 
'   from hacking attempts. A complete list of available functions and 
'   symbols can be found in the two variables C_VALID_CALC_CHARS and 
'   C_VALID_CALC_FUNCTIONS.
Function Calculate(expression)
    Dim rV
    rV = ""
    If expression & "" <> "" Then
        Dim t, c, v
        'Validate first...
        t = expression
        'Strip out all standard characters...
        For c = 1 to Len(C_VALID_CALC_CHARS)
            t = Replace(t, Mid(C_VALID_CALC_CHARS, c, 1), " ")
        Next 'c
        'Strip out multiple spaces...
        Do While Instr(t, "  ") > 0
            t = Replace(t, "  ", " ")
        Loop
        t = Trim(t)
        'Check what we're left with...
        v = t = ""
        If Not v Then
            Dim f
            f = Split(t, " ")
            v = True
            For c = 0 To UBound(f, 1)
                v = Instr(C_VALID_CALC_FUNCTIONS, f(c)) > 0
            Next 'f
        End If
        'Define the return value...
        If v Then
            rV = Eval(expression)
        Else
            rV = "Invalid Expression!"
        End If
    End If
    Calculate = rV
End Function
```

It may not be the fastest way to do it, especially if you're using it frequently, but you could use it as a way of validating an equation before launching into it.

I did test it a little while ago, but let me know if you have any problems.